# Managing Game Entity coordinates

Tags: opengl, matrix, entity-system

In my Game I'm currently have "Scene Coordinates" which are the X,Y coordinates relative to a Game Scene.

In that Scene there are Game Entities, let's say there's a GameEntity **A** in x=100.0, y=100.0 ( scene coordinates )

Which is the best way to have "Entity Coordinates" so that from GameEntity **A** point of view, he's standing at x=0.0, y=0.0 with OpenGL transformations?

In that way if I apply something like

```
glRotatef(angle, 0, 0, 1)
```

The entity will rotate around it's own origin and not the scene "global" origin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of transformations in OpenGL is the opposite order than for DirectX. For DirectX its the SRT-Rule: Scale, Rotate, Translate - for OpenGL its: Translate, Rotate, Scale

```
glPushMatrix();
    // move entity to its position
    glTranslate(...);
    // rotate entity around its origin
    glRotate(...);
    // drawn entity
    DrawEntity();
glPopMatrix();
```

DrawEntity must render the entity using its local space coordsystem, they are fixed if there is no animation.

If that doesnt answer your question, please rephrase it and elaborate.